# Javamail getContent() fatal error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to make an app to "simply" read a plain text email (and only plain text. I send the email, so I know it's only plain text).
I pick up code here and there to do it.
I finnaly succeed in reading "from" "subject" "sentDate" and else, but not "content". And it's content that I want to read...
All is working fine, but when I call **getContent()**, I've got a fatal error.

I'm using javax.mail.jar = javamail 1.6.2 in app\libs.
I've tried with mail.jar and activation.jar, and it doesn't work.
I've tried to put all reading code into a "void" and doesn't work.

Even when typing

```
Object content = message.getContent();
```

It doesn't work...

In the manifest, I've got

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In the build.graddle(module app) i've got

```
compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
```

The mainActivity.java:

```
package myName.myAPP;


import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String msg = "";
        String from;
        String subject;
        String sentDate;
        String contentType


        // -----------------------------------------------StricMode ERROR--------------------------------------
        // Ces deux lignes sont à ajouter si l'on veut éviter une erreur:
        // at android.os.strictmode$androidblockguardpolicy.onnetwork
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        // -----------------------------------------------StricMode ERROR--------------------------------------

        Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(connectionProperties,null);
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect("pop.free.fr", "user", "password");
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = folderInbox.getMessages();

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
                from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                subject = message.getSubject();
                sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();
                contentType = message.getContentType();

                String content = message.getContent().toString();  

                msg = msg + from + subject + sentDate + contentType + " %%%%% ";
            }
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.MsgContent)).setText(msg);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String trace = sw.toString();
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.MsgContent)).setText(trace);
        }
    }
}
```

When running, the app crashes.
The logcat is below (when running on GenyMotion):

```
07-02 00:08:29.031 2419-2419/myName.myAPP E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myName.myAPP, PID: 2419
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getDataHandler(MimeMessage.java:1475)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1508)
at myName.myAPP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-02 00:08:35.380 2419-2431/myName.myAPP E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
07-02 00:08:35.381 2419-2431/myName.myAPP E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.net.Socket.close()' on a null object reference
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.close(Protocol.java:382)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.close(POP3Folder.java:296)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.finalize(POP3Folder.java:576)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
[ 07-02 00:08:36.272    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection
[ 07-02 00:08:38.284    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection
[ 07-02 00:08:40.297    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection
```

I've checked. j`avax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler` is in javax.mail.jar

I'm lost.
Need help to proceed.

Hope my english better than my java.

Comment: It looks like the JavaMail classes are not being included in your packaged application.  General JavaMail instructions for Android are [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think so, but I don't undersand why. Why JavaMail class work perfectly with .getFrom() .getSentDate() .getSubject() .getcontentType() but not with .getContent(). However it's the same library. I put javax.mail.jar in app/libs folder and include in the app with "Project structure>Dependancies" in AndroidStudio. It adds "compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')" in my graddle.

Comment: If (as shown in javaMail web site) I put "compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2' " and "compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'" it throw an error :"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sun/mail/auth/MD4;"

Comment: Don't know what to do with "javax.mail.jar". Compile or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paradise exists.

To resolve the problem, "javax.mail.jar" mustn't be compiled, but ***PROVIDED***.
The Build.gradle(module:app) is as shown:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myNam.myAPP"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
    provided files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
}
```

Important lines are:

```
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
    }
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
    }
dependencies {
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
    provided files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
}
```

With this, it works prefectly.
One week of despair and cry.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not a gradle or Android expert, but...  If you remove your copy of javax.mail.jar and remove the provided line, does it work?  I thought the compile line would do everything needed to include it in your application.

Comment: No. Need javax.mail.jar to be provided or compiled for the import in mainActivity.java. If I remove the javax.mail.jar line, import.javax.mail.* are in RED on mainActivity.

Comment: Doesn't the "compile" line do that?